# Error when using UNION - Query failed: All subqueries in an UNION must have the same column names

Tags: memgraphdb

I have this code

```
MATCH (ca:CatAsi {name: "Car"})-[]->(c:Cat)-[]->(p) 
RETURN c
UNION
MATCH (ca:CatAsi {name: "Car"})-[]->(c:Cat)-[]->(p) 
RETURN p
```

and I get the error

```
 Query failed: All subqueries in an UNION must have the same column names.
```

I use the same name, View. Why then this error?